# \section causes citations to display as [0]

Tags: biblatex, input

I have a main `.tex` file where I input some chapters which are other `.tex` files. Then I have a bibliography that I input in the main. If I have some `\section` in my input file, some citation become "[0]".

This is the `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\linespread{1.3} 
\usepackage[textheight=\textheight,textwidth=\textwidth,bindingoffset=3cm,vcentering]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty,lmodern}
\usepackage{float} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, defernumbers=true, refsection=section]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib/references.bib}

\graphicspath{ {img/} }
\chapternumberfont{\fontsize{20pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
\chaptertitlefont{\fontsize{20pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2pc plus 2pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[begintext=“, endtext=”]{quoting}
\SetBlockEnvironment{quoting}
\SetBlockThreshold{1} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\usepackage[citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarks=true
}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter one}
\input{chapters/chapter01}

\newpage
\printbibliography[keyword={biblio}, heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliography}]
\newpage
\printbibliography[keyword={site}, heading=bibintoc, title={Sitography}]
\end{document}
```

This is `references.bib`:

```
@online{addm,
url = {https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/autism/addm-community-report/key-findings.html},
keywords     = {site}
}

@article{kenny2016terms,
  title={Which terms should be used to describe autism? Perspectives from the UK autism community},
  author={Kenny, Lorcan and Hattersley, Caroline and Molins, Bonnie and Buckley, Carole and Povey, Carol and Pellicano, Elizabeth},
  journal={Autism},
  volume={20},
  number={4},
  pages={442--462},
  year={2016},
  publisher={SAGE Publications Sage UK: London, England},
  keywords = {biblio}  
}
```

and this is `chapter01.tex`

```
\section{Terminology and Data}
STUFF STUFF STUFF\cite{addm} 

\section{Therapies}
stuff\cite{kenny2016terms} stuff\cite{addm}
```

The strange thing is that the citations after the second `\section` are working, while the one after the first `\section` not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `\input` and can be reproduced in a much smaller setting, where it is easier to diagnose the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers=true, refsection=section]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter one}
\section{Section One}
Lorem\cite{sigfridsson,worman}

\section{Section Two}
ipsum\cite{sigfridsson} dolor\cite{ctan}

\newpage
\printbibliography[nottype=online, heading=bibintoc, title={Bibliography}]
\newpage
\printbibliography[type=online, heading=bibintoc, title={Sitography}]
\end{document}
```

Note how all citations in the first section are displayed as "[0]" and how only the references in the second section get numbers. The bibliographies only show the entries of the second section. `worman` (which was only cited in the first section) is nowhere to be seen.

The culprit is `refsection=section` and the problem is exacerbated (which was an extreme stroke of luck here, since otherwise it might have gone unnoticed) by `defernumbers=true`.

With `refsection=section` you tell `biblatex` to start a new refsection at each `\section` command in your document. In particular *Section One* and *Section Two* are in two different refsections. Refsections are a way to organise completely independent bibliographies and citations. They are kept separate from each other and each refsection has its own sorting and numbering. The `\printbibliography`s you issue belong to the second refsection opened for *Section Two* and will thus only pick up the citations from there. That explains why we never get to see `worman` in any of the bibliographies – it was only cited in the first section.

Things go a bit further, as far as `biblatex` is concerned, the entry `sigfridsson` in the first section is completely independent of `sigfridsson` in the second section, they just share the same entry data. In particular they need not have the same label number (cite label) or sort the same. Since you use `defernumbers` entries will be assigned their label number not based on the overall sorting. Instead they get their label number when they first appear in a bibliography. That's why `sigfridsson` in the second section is "[1]" and `ctan` is "[2]" even though alphabetically `ctan` would be sorted before `sigfridsson`. (Change to `defernumbers=false` to see this.) The entries from the first section never appear in any bibliography and thus are never assigned any number. Hence, they always show "[0]".

There are several ways to resolve this.

- Add a `\printbibliography` for each `\section` to obtain independent per-`\section` bibliographies.
- Switch to `refsection=chapter` to produce independent bibliographies and citations per `\chapter` and not per `\section`.
- Drop the `refsection` option altogether to produce a global bibliography and global citations across all chapters.

Comment: `refsection=chapter` solved the problem!